# all of my low quality review posts comes blank

Tags: support, review, low-quality

[image]

Look over the above picture, while reviewing I found an empty [post](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/230339) but while clicked on edit I was able to get this [answer](https://superuser.com/posts/752301/revisions).

Am I the only one who's getting this type of errors? What would be the probable solution and cause to this

Comment: Looks like the OP edited the answer to be two dots and lots of spaces. That is _clear_ from the revisions you have linked. That edit should be rolled back.

Comment: I have rolled this back - the review now shows the rolled back revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oded mentioned, the poster [vandalized the post](https://superuser.com/revisions/752301/6) to just ". ." on both of his answers. They have been rolled back